# Integrating over a moving boundary dependent on a velocity vector?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've somehow never encountered this type of integral bound so I don't know how it changes the term I'm working on.

Here's the term I started with:
$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(\int f(\bar{r}, E, \bar{\Omega }, t)dV)$, V=const.

Accounting for the boundary moving I can use Gauss's theorem to get:
$\int( \frac{\partial  f(\bar{r}, E, \bar{\Omega }, t) }{\partial t} + \triangledown \cdot f(\bar{r}, E, \bar{\Omega }, t)\bar{\Omega } ) dV$, V=V(t)

From here, I need to account for the volume being dependent on time and a velocity vector: $V(\bar{v}(\bar{r},t), t)$

Can someone please help me know where I need to go from here?

Comment: What are E and $\Omega$?

Comment: Energy and a directional unit vector.

Comment: You can look-up for Riemann transport theorem. This integral is commonly encountered in fluid mechanics.